# Why doesn't my plugin load its dependencies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs, underscore.js

I working on an app that uses require.js to load dependencies. I have also written a plugin for jQuery that is used in the app. The jQuery plugin depends on Underscore but does not support AMD. My problem is that Underscore isn't available to my plugin when running the app.

Some code snippets:

`index.js`

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js/app",
    paths: {
        underscore: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min",
        myPlugin: '../lib/myPlugin/myPlugin.js',
    },
    shim: {
        underscore_global: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        myPlugin: {'deps': ['jquery', 'underscore']},
    }
});
```

Where my plugin is used:

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var $ = require('jquery'),
        myPlugin = require('myPlugin')
```

The console says that Underscore (`_`) is undefined when the plugin tries to call functions on it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin depends on `underscore`. This is *NOT* an AMD module, thus does not `define()` anything, as far as RequireJS is concerned. (Actually it defines something in global scope, but Require doesn't care about this.) This is why you have the `underscore_global` shim. I would suggest the following change:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        underscore_global: {
            exports: '_',
            deps: ['underscore']
        },
        myPlugin: {'deps': ['jquery', 'underscore_global']},
        ...
    }
});
```